# How to enable using PgUp/PgDn in ftplugin/man.vim (man pages viewer in vim, key "K")

Tags: vim

There is a plugin for vim `ftplugin/man.vim`: 
https://github.com/idbrii/vim-man/blob/master/ftplugin/man.vim

> " man page filetype plugin file

With it I can view man page directly from vim by pressing "K".

But scrolling in this internal man page viewer does not work with pgup/pgdn keys. Yes, there are some other variants of scroll, but how to enable pgdn/pgup in this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to vimrc:

```
:let manpageview_multimanpage=0
```

pgup-pgdn mapped to changing sections of mans (when man is called with `man -a` and there is the same page in different sections). Documentation is at http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/doc/manpageview.txt.html

```
                g:manpageview_multimanpage
g:manpageview_multimanpage (=1 by default)
        This option means that the PageUp and PageDown keys
        will be mapped to move to the next and previous manpage
        in a multi-man-page buffer.  Such buffers result with
        the "man -a" option.  As an example:
            :Man -a printf
```